# Why to I have a "one-time, first-time" error on my isLoggedIn observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I know this is hard to believe, but Observables are kind of tricky and I don't 100% get them.  :-)

Given this code:

```
  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  public currentUser: Observable<User>;
  private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.tokenIsValid());

  ...

  get isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    this.loggedIn.next(this.tokenIsValid());
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
  }

  private tokenIsValid(): boolean {
    let currentUser: User = this.currentUserValue;
    if (currentUser) {
      const token = currentUser.token;
      const tokenInfo = this.getDecodedAccessToken(token);
      if (Date.now() <= tokenInfo.exp * 1000) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  private getDecodedAccessToken(token: string): any {
    try {
      return jwt_decode(token);
    } catch (Error) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Why does `isLoggedIn` report `true` when it shouldn't only one time (the first time after logout), and then work perfectly thereafter?

Here's the sequence:

1. I login in with JWT with nice, testable 15 second time out.
2. I go to a protected resource and see it.
3. I wait way more 15 seconds for the JWT to expire
4. I go to another protected resource, and I can see it.
5. I go back to the initial protected resource, and I can't see it.
6. I go back yet again to the second protected resource, and I can't see it.

And by "see it", I mean I am not prohibited by my AuthGuard to see the page.

My question then is why the error only the first time?

ADDED:  Here's the constructor for the AuthenticationService class, if that helps:

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.currUser)));
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }
```

Comment: Can you please give more context about the code? This code belongs to which file? A stackblitz would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the full context of your question but I see a potential problem in this piece of code

```
  get isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    this.loggedIn.next(this.tokenIsValid());
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
  }
```

Here it seems you are trying to do 2 things

1. First you notify if the user is logged in with `this.loggedIn.next(this.tokenIsValid())`
2. Then you return the `Subject` (as an `Observable`) used to broadcast to all interested party the above notification

The point is that every party (e.g. your AuthGuard) which wants to be notified when something happens **first** has to subscribe to the Observable it is interested in, and **only** **then** it gets any notification when the Observable emits.

This means that you have to find a way for your interested party to first subscribe to `loggedIn` as Observable with something like

```
  get isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
  }
```

and only then find the right place to make `loggedIn` emit something via `this.loggedIn.asObservable()`.

If rather the point is that you want to receive a notification for an event even if it has happened before the subscription, you have to use ReplySubject and not BehaviorSubject.

Comment: perfect!  That was exactly it.  I subscribed in my AuthGuard to the observable, assigned the isLoggedIn value there, and it worked perfectly.  Thank you.